# Clearing IE8 float

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, css-float, ie8-compatibility-mode

Code in question is [link no longer allowed]

Sadly I cannot share the actual site as this is under NDA. The above code is stripped best possible to accomodate this yet give you enough info for the issue.

The left navigation is using jquery stickem https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem
This isn't set up through the jsbin but I figured I should post this info.

**The current issue:**

I am getting undesired floats in IE8 but in ie7 it's fine and it's okay when in IE8 compatibility mode.

Screen shot at: i.stack.imgur.com/pJNIq.jpg

The stickem sticky nav is fixed position to the left, so the content is floated right, but in ie8 the content does not float all the way. Does anyone know why this might be? If you use the crumby IE dev tools, you can untick the float:right off and see that it IS in fact floating right, but not all the way to the right of the container.

Comment: Which element is floated right? I'm only seeing the nav floated left, the main content is using auto margins to center it on the page.

Comment: I honestly have no clue about what 'floating right' you are talking. The left bar container is floating left. All elements in it are 'blocks', meaning they expand to the size of their parent and the final `a` element has padding. This will make it being displayed 20px to the right, but obviously it doesn't go all the way to the right.